# Review form it's not submitting in Django

Tags: json, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-urls

Am creating a review page in Django with a help of *Jason*.

But when l try to submit the form, it returns an error that **page not found**

I would like to seek from anyone to who can get where l did a mistake in my codes

Lastly when l trying on
`a=ActionGame.objects.get(id=id)` it returns an error that *id not defined*

**Am requesting any support and l welcome any idea**

**Action/Views.py**

```
#Add action game description detail function





def action_description(request, description):
    description=get_object_or_404(Action_Game,slug=description)
   
    
    #getting each game reviews
    reviews = ActionGameReview.objects.filter(game_name=get_object_or_404(Action_Game, game_name=description))
    #getting latest 4 game review
    lt_reviews = reviews[:4]
    #getting Average Review
    avg_rating=ActionGameReview.objects.filter(game_name=get_object_or_404(Action_Game, game_name=description)).aggregate(rating=Avg('rate'))
    #game review form
    review_form=ActionReviewForm()
   
    context={
        'description':description,
        'action_ds_random':action_ds_random,
        'reviews':reviews,
        
        'lt_reviews':lt_reviews,
        'avg_rating':avg_rating,
        
        
        'review_form':review_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'Blog/action-description.html', context)
```

```
#Add review function 

def ajax_add_review(request, descript):
    game_review=ActionGameReview.objects.get(game_name=get_object_or_404(Action_Game, game_name=descript))
    user=request.user
    review = Action_Game.objects.create(
        user=user,
        game_name=game_name,
        subject=request.POST['subject'],
        rate=request.POST['rete']
    )
    context={
        'user':user.username,
        'subject':request.POST['subject'],
        'rate':request.POST['rate'],
    }
    avg_rating=ActionGameReview.objects.get(game_name=get_object_or_404(Action_Game, game_name=descript)).aggregate(rating=Avg('rate'))
    
    return JsonResponse(
        {
        'bool': True,
        'context': context,
        'avg_rating':avg_rating,
        
        }
    )
```

**Action/function.js***

```
console.log("working fine");



$("#commentForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        data: $(this).serialize(),


        method: $(this).attr("method"),

        url: $(this).attr("action"),

        dataType: "json",

        success: function(response){
            console.log('Saved comment to db..')
        }
    })

   
})
```

**Action/url.py**

```
path('action/<slug:description>/',views.action_description, name='action_description'),






    #add review
    path('ajax-add-review/<slug:descript>/', views.ajax_add_review, name='ajax_add_review'),
```

**Blog/action-description.html**

```
 <hr>
.......
    <form action="{% url 'ajax_add_review' description.slug   %}" method="POST" id="commentForm" class="commentForm">
      {% csrf_token %}
......
```

[image: image showing the console results in chrome when l try to submit the message or alert]